# VLC: avformat demux error: Unknown option "threads"

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, matroska

I transcoded a video with FFmpeg using

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 18 \
  -c:v libx265 -x265-params preset=slower:crf=25:keyint=240 \
  -c:a libopus -b:a 192k -filter:a aformat=channel_layouts=7.1|5.1|stereo \
  -c:s copy -y output.mkv
```

but can't play back the Matroska video file in VLC because:

```
VLC media player 2.2.5.1 Umbrella (revision 2.2.5.1~ppa)
[00007fc370c01948] avformat demux error: Unknown option "threads"
```

In fact VLC doesn't even see the video stream in the codec information list. I can play back the video fine with Totem (though audio doesn't work because it can't decode Opus) or if I re-multiplex the video stream into an MPEG4 file container.

**What's causing this issue and, more importantly, how can I solve or work around it?**

Info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 (amd64)
- [60 seconds sample](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~foerstda/stuff/avformat-error.sample.mkv) of the video file in question
- FFmpeg info:

  ```
  ffprobe version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
    configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --disable-ffserver --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab --enable-libwavpack --enable-nvenc --enable-libzimg
    libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
    libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
    libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
    libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
    libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
    libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
    libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
    libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
    libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
  Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'avformat-error.sample.mkv':
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavf57.71.100
    Duration: 00:01:00.12, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 961 kb/s
      Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
      Metadata:
        ENCODER         : Lavc57.89.100 libx265
        DURATION        : 00:01:00.115000000
      Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default)
      Metadata:
        ENCODER         : Lavc57.89.100 libopus
        DURATION        : 00:01:00.001000000
      Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
      Metadata:
        title           : English
        DURATION        : 00:00:00.000000000
  ```

Comment: Works for me using VLC 2.2.6.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Thanks for the hint! With VLC 2.2.6 from `pp:jonathonf/vlc` VLC displays the correct stream information in the codec pane but the decoded video remains black and I can't play back Opus streams. No error messages on the terminal.

Comment: I tested on Arch Linux. Maybe your package provider will know what the problem is.